# Questions about the specifics of Factory Reset

Tags: factory-reset

I have a few questions about how exactly Factory Reset works on Android (10+) devices:

Specifically, what is, and what is not, wiped?

I know that **app** data is wiped, but are there any **system** databases/caches/logs (basically anything that contains any form of user-specific data) left untouched by the process?

Does Android do the same thing as Apple, where the old data is left completely encrypted?

Thanks

Comment: android partitions are mounted read-only except for userdata partition which is formatted on factory reset, and frp partition which survives